# Import CSV in Jira and linking

Tags: csv, jira

I'm trying to create a CSV of Stories and Sub-tasks so I can import it into Jira.

I link the Sub-tasks with their Stories in the following way:

[image]

Where I map `Issue Key` to `Issue Id`:

[image]

But I'm not sure about it, since this "Issue Id" looks to be for linking, isn't it? If it's so, to what field I should map to? For `Parent Id` I obviously map to `Parent Id`.

Each Story has also a field that I would like to use for linking to an existing Jira ticket.